# Matrix output formatting - how to add scientific notation as a matrix multiplier in front of matrix output

Tags: math, matrix, vector, scientific-notation

SCREENSHOT OF IDEAL OUTPUT:

[image: SCREENSHOT OF IDEAL OUTPUT]

I am currently producing vectors and matrices and would like to format them so that the printed matrix displays only one digit  before the decimal point (eg x.2, x.8 instead of xyz.2 or xyz.8) in each of the matrix elements. The Jupyter code below shows how they are currently formatted, and the screenshot (link above) shows how I would like the code to be formatted. Hence, I would like to automatically put a scientific notation matrix multiplier (eg 1 x 10^x...or in python terms "1ex") in front of the outputted matrix. If possible, I would like to have this set at the start of my code so that it could be applied to x amount of matrices without having to call a function that achieves this. Thanks very much.

JUPYTER CODE OUTPUT:

```
[[  888888.8888889        0.         1333333.3333333        0.               0.               0.       ]
 [       0.        33333333.3333333        0.               0.               0.               0.       ]
 [ 1333333.3333333        0.         2666666.6666667        0.               0.               0.       ]
 [       0.               0.               0.               0.               0.               0.       ]
 [       0.               0.               0.               0.               0.               0.       ]
 [       0.               0.               0.               0.               0.               0.       ]]
```

I tried formatting options at the start of my Jupyter notebook under the np.set_printoptions

Comment: [Please remember](/help/how-to-ask) to [format your post](/markdown) properly.

Comment: Add LaTeX to your notebook and use it to format data.  Might be difficult to generalize.  Your "ideal" is only good for small matricies.

Comment: Interesting idea, I know the Matlab front end will apply that heuristic. As to how to get that effect in Jupyter, my advice is to ask on a Jupyter-specific forum (I don't know what that might be). Also I think you need to say what language you're using (Python, R, etc).

Comment: find `x = max(abs(matrix elements));` then compute multiplier `m` as `mexp = ceil(log10(x)); m=10^mexp;` and simply divide your matrix by `m`  and print the elements without scientific notation like `%.4lf` in C++ formatting style...